# KDE apps (Kate and Dolphin) save the session only on close

Tags: kde-plasma, kate

If the KDE apps inside my Linux box are not closed properly, i.e., they are killed or they go down with a system crash, then they forget the latest session including opened files and changes.
Is this because some of these session files are stored on a tmpfs or a memory mapped file or something similar? I am not sure if I changed such a setting.
How can we make KDE apps save the session to disk when the session is changed (not only when the apps are closed)? And where are these session files stored? Thanks.